# Serialise a WKB into WKT or geojson in flask marshmallow/marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, jsonserializer, geoalchemy2

I've got a bunch of GIS tables in my model that I created in flaskSQLAlchemy. Each of these models has a 'geom' field which is a WKB object.
Which need to be JSON serialized into WKT or geojson, So that The API GET call would work.

I tried to use geoalchemy2 functions, but I'm stuck.
I use a flask marshmallow/marshmallow-sqlalchemy combo, and I tried something like the following, with no luck.

```py
from geoalchemy2 import functions
from marshmallow import fields

class WKTSerializationField(fields.Field):
def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj):
    if value is None:
        return value
    else:
        if type(value).__name__ == 'WKBElement':
            return functions.ST_AsEWKT(value)
        else:
            return None



class GISModelTableSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
       model = GISModelTable
    geom = WKTSerializationField(attribute="geom")
```

Please provide a code example if you can, how to serialize/deserialize a field in marshmallow alchemy. Or any answer is welcomed at this point.

Comment: [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233184/converting-geoalchemy2-elements-wkbelement-to-wkt) might help

Comment: did you ever solve this?  up against the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) *'fields.Method()'* and in the method use another method *'to_shape*' from [geoalchemy2.shape](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.4/index.html) package. This will help you with serialization issue.

```
    #!schemas.py
    from marshmallow import fields
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
    from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape
    from .models import YourModel
    
    class YourModelSchema(ModelSchema):
        your_geom_field = fields.Method("geom_to_dict")
        
        @staticmethod
        def geom_to_dict(obj):
            point = to_shape(obj.your_geom_field)
            return { 
                      lat: point.y,
                      lon: point.x
                   }
    
        class Meta:
              model = YourModel
              exclude = ("your_geom_field")
```

this migh help you with serialization, for desirialization you may read more detailed in [geoalchemy2](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.4/index.html) api reference

Try to code all required fields by yourself, you may get more specific serialization in a form you want